# Diagonal squares on a chessboard

Tags: combinatorics

A problem asks to count the number of possible choices for 4 squares on a chessboard such that they don't all lie on a diagonal line.

It is manageable to do this problem by subtracting the bad cases from $\binom{64}{4}$ and even the calculation of bad cases can be simplified using Pascal's identity.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: It's hard to imagine that any method of counting the "good" cases directly can be more elegant than (elegantly) counting the "bad" cases and subtracting from $\binom{n^2}4$. By "Pascal's identity" do you mean the identity $\binom xn =\binom{x-1}n+\binom{x-1}{n-1}$? I don't see how that is particularly useful here. I'd use what Robert Z. quaintly calls the "hockey stick identity".

Answer (score 1):

The bad cases are not so difficult to find for a $n\times n$ board:
$$2\binom{n}{4}+4\sum_{k=4}^{n-1}\binom{k}{4}=2\binom{n}{4}+4\binom{n}{5}$$
where we used the [Hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity).